# setState not triggered from onChange method of CreatableSelect

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to use *react-select*'s **CreatableSelect** to get an input from the user. I have configured the methods *onCreateOption* and *onChange* to handle new options and clear selection respectively. Sample code 
 is at this [URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/k1o7m7zwo3). I am also copying the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/lib/Creatable";
import clonedeep from "lodash.clonedeep";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectOption1: null,
      selectOption2: null,
      selectedOptions: {
        option1Value: null,
        option2Value: null
      }
    };
  }

  handleOption1 = option => {
    let selectedOptions = clonedeep(this.state.selectedOptions);
    selectedOptions.option1Value = option;
    this.setState({
      selectedOptions,
      selectOption1: { label: option, value: option }
    });
  };

  handleOption1Change = (option, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    let selectedOptions = clonedeep(this.state.selectedOptions);
    selectedOptions.option1Value = null;
    if (action === "clear" || action === "pop-value") {
      console.log(action);
      this.setState({ selectedOptions, selectOption1: null });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        value={this.state.selectOption1}
        backspaceRemovesValue={true}
        escapeClearsValue={true}
        isClearable={true}
        placeholder="Enter First name"
        formatCreateLabel={inValue => inValue.toUpperCase()}
        noOptionsMessage={() => null}
        onCreateOption={this.handleOption1}
        onChange={this.handleOption1Change}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My problem now is whenever i try to clear the select option, the onChange mehtod is getting triggered but the setState inside the onChange does not do anything.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my handleOption1Change mehtod. The parameter action is not a string but an object. So my handleOption1Change should have been as below.

```
 handleOption1Change = (option, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    let selectedOptions = clonedeep(this.state.selectedOptions);
    selectedOptions.option1Value = null;
    if (action.action === "clear" || action.action === "pop-value") {
      console.log(action);
      this.setState({ selectedOptions, option1Value: null });
    }
  };
```

Notice the if condition at line 5.